# Example of Matching Dimension for Strict Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $V$ be an $F$-vector space with $U$ a strict subspace of $V$.

1. Show that, if $\dim F(V) < \infty$, then $\dim F(U) < \dim F(V)$.
2. Give examples of $F, V$, and $U$ as above such that $\dim F(U) = \dim F(V)$.

Part (1), is simple, based on linear independence and size of bases.  However, I can't seem to come up with an example for part (2).  I know that $V$ must be infinite dimensional based on (1) but I can't find an example.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomials functions  $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ (with real coefficients) is a vector space over $ \Bbb R$

The polynomials functions  $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ (with real coefficients) that verify $P(0) = 0$ is a strict subspace of the one before, but both have the same dimension